# How can I search multiple PDF files that have OCR?

Tags: pdf, search, ocr

I have thousands upon thousands of PDF files that have OCR. It's great when you have one open but I want to be able to find PDF files in a folder that contain X. Adobe seems to have something build in but it takes quite some time to process -- I figured once the OCR was done it would be a faster process.

Any advice or tips on how to manage this would be great. Ideally a recommendation on search software for Windows 7 that supports this. Thanks!

Comment: AIUI, PDF files contain searchable text and/or contain non-searchable images of scanned text. You can use OCR on images to extract searchable  text that then is incorporated in a PDF file. What do you mean by "PDF files that have OCR"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDFs have already been OCRed you should be able to use an indexed search product like Windows Search (you may need to tweak indexing settings) or a 3rd party product like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack).

Answer (score 0):

I use [PDF-Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads) for searching through directories of PDFs. It is quite fast.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copernic desktop search (pro may be better for you imho)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/) -- one of the best document search options out there.